# Unable to make changes in Android SDK manager, trying to install Android SDK Platform 25

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I am new to Android Studio and I am getting the following error in my command prompt when trying to build Cordova application for Android:

> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
>   [Android SDK Platform 25].
>   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
>   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

I searched the web for other people with this same error, and a number of folks said they had success by navigating to the SDK Manager inside Android studio and "checking" the necessary packages (I figured I would need to install Android SDK Platform 25, as that is what the error message says I am missing).

However, inside the Android SDK manager I am unable to click on any of the boxes or even the different menu tabs that say "SDK Tools" and "SDK Update Sites". I don't know what to do if I cannot click on any of the boxes inside this window.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xgsv.png)
 of my SDK manager screen, where I cannot modify any of the checked or unchecked boxes.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should rename the folder which contains the SDK as it contains a white space or move the SDK to some other folder in some other drive.

Option 1: Remove the whitespace between **Mari Kamiya** to **Mari_Kamiya** which I think you can't do.

Option 2: Copy the SDK from the current location to a different folder which doesn't have a white space in its whole path and then change the "Android SDK Location" to the directory where you copied the SDK.